# How to use Suspense in React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to test the new Suspense feature from React 18, but without success. I studied the documentation and I do everything according to the procedure, but I never see Loading.

In the sample code, I load data from api and then render it. If the api does not load completely, I want to view the `<p>Loading...</p>` But it doesn't work.

```js
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const Movie = ({ title, year }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{year}</p>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

But if I do this, everything is fine.

```js
import React from "react";

const Movie = ({ title, year }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {!title ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p>{year}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

So how exactly does Suspense work?

Thanks

Comment: `I studied the documentation` Which documentation are you referring to? Suspense for data loading is technically possible, but not really convenient, and not nearly as simple as the code you've written.

Comment: Hello, I meant the original React documentation. In addition to Suspense, React.lazy is also used there, but lazy didn't  help me achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yeah, at the moment, suspense is most useful with React.lazy. They do *plan* to make suspense useful for data loading, but at the moment, it's inconvenient and not recommended. The second example you wrote is what i would recommend you do.